# How can I identify the element "disabled"

Tags: xpath

[image]

`<div class="tiktok-j5tm11-DivCodeInputContainer e2oypfg0"><div class="code-input e2oypfg1 tiktok-1ng3k1k-DivInputContainer-StyledBaseInput etcs7ny0"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter 6-digit code" class="tiktok-11to27l-InputContainer etcs7ny1" value=""><div class="tiktok-txpjn9-DivIconContainer etcs7ny2"></div></div><button type="button" data-e2e="send-code-button" class="tiktok-1y4en69-ButtonSendCode e1gzcpl10" disabled="">Resend code: 50s</button></div>`

I tried with //button[@data-e2e='send-code-button']

but when request to send code "disabled" will appear, so i want to select it to determine when request to get code has been sent

Comment: It's not clear. Do you want to indicate if element is disabled? What code you sending there? With what tool?

Comment: I am creating tiktok account. I can only copy the above HTML code because every time I submit the code there will be a 1 minute countdown to resend the code and in that 1 minute the word " disabled" will appear, I want to select it

Comment: OK, what tools are you using? F.e. Selenium?

Comment: i use browserautomationstudio software, but i just want help about the xpath, i think it's the same

Comment: OK, so, you want XPath to locate that element before it becomes disabled, after it became disabled in in any case with no dependency to disabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select button after `@disabled` added try

```
//button[@data-e2e='send-code-button' and @disabled]
```